# Copy attribute values based on a preceding node attribute with Groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm trying to do something in SoapUi with Groovy and it's not working.

I have multiple nodes with many attributes and I need to extract the child node attribute based of a parent's attribute

For example:

```
<library id="82389389">
    <book id="123" bookType="SF">
        <price id="325" priceValue="5"/>
    </book>
    <book id="4741" bookType="History">
        <price id="12388" priceValue="15"/>
    </book>
    <book id="2626" bookType="Drama">
        <price id="12145" priceValue="40"/>
    </book>
</library>
```

In this XML I need to extract priceValue based on the bookType and use it somewhere else (the order of the book nodes is changing)

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
def response = .../library[1]

def i=0
def records = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
def size = records.book.size()

for (i=0,i<size,i++)
{
    bookType1 = records.book[i].@bookType.first().value().text();
    if (bookType1 == 'History')
    {
        def priceValueBook = records.book[i].price.@priceValue.first().value().text()
        log.info priceValueBook 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear exactly at what point you are trying to do this, but the following would work in SoapUI script step:

```
context.expand('${test_step#Response#//*:book[@bookType="History"]/*:price/@priceValue}')
```

Comment: This works and actually makes my life easier with other SoapUi requests.
 Thanks!